# How to change dtype of each dataframe column to float if it best fits?

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

I have an excel that has columns with values like `1.32131**`, among columns of dtype `string`. As a result the dtypes of these columns in the dataframe are `object`. I have cleaned the asterisks from the dataframe and now I need to convert the dtypes of these columns to `float64`. I am aware of ways to do it if I define the columns that need to be changed or the desired dtypes for each column (like the functions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas)), but I have too many columns to use such solutions. Thus I am looking for a more efficient and clean way.

For example, if I wanted to convert to `int64` I would use [`convert_dtypes()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes), but it seems that it doesn't support floats and it returns these columns with `object` dtype.

> Then, if possible, convert to StringDtype, BooleanDtype or an
> appropriate integer extension type, otherwise leave as object.

Right now I am using the following script that works but I think it's to big for its purpose and it a bit slow.

```
# Create df and clean it
# note that the data exist in an excel normally and the dict is only for reproducibility purposes
dict = {'Name':['BPh1', 'BPh2', 'BPh3', 'BPh4', 'BPh5', 'BPh6', 'BPh7'], 'BBB':['2.00755**', '2.7766**', '0.490127**','0.490127**', '0.87667**', '0.899189**', '3.084**'], 'Buffer_solubility_mg_L':['0.00112934**','0.000798559**', '0.000218191**', '0.000122249**', '0.00382848**', '0.00109165**', '0.000665366**'], 'CYP_2C19_inhibition':['Inhibitor','Inhibitor','Non','Non','Inhibitor','Inhibitor',
'Inhibitor']}

ss =  pd.DataFrame(dict).replace("\*",'',regex=True)

# Convert dtype to float when possible
for col in ss.columns[1:]:
    print(col,'\n',ss[col].dtypes)
    try:
        ss[col] = pd.to_numeric(ss[col])
    except:
        pass
    print(ss[col].dtypes,'\n')
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this conversion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change column type in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas) -- I mean `astype()` or `infer_objects()` in the first answer that you haven't tried.

Comment: I dont think so because I have to define the columns or the dtypes in case of `astype()` or I have to already have floats in object dtype in the case of `infer_objects()`

Answer (score 0):

I'd change/clean the values before creating the dataframe, that way you're not first creating one, and then converting it to something else (might save a little bit of time as well). The advantage is that you can do it in a single line. I don't think you can get much faster than this, given the input data that you have to work with.

```py
import pandas

# Create df and clean it
dict = {'Name':['BPh1', 'BPh2', 'BPh3', 'BPh4', 'BPh5', 'BPh6', 'BPh7'], 'BBB':['2.00755**', '2.7766**', '0.490127**','0.490127**', '0.87667**', '0.899189**', '3.084**'], 'Buffer_solubility_mg_L':['0.00112934**','0.000798559**', '0.000218191**', '0.000122249**', '0.00382848**', '0.00109165**', '0.000665366**'], 'CYP_2C19_inhibition':['Inhibitor','Inhibitor','Non','Non','Inhibitor','Inhibitor',
'Inhibitor']}

# Perform the conversion on creation
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        col: pandas.to_numeric([v.replace("*", "") for v in values], errors="ignore")
        for col, values in dict.items()
    }
)
```

Comment: thanks for answering. do you think its possible with an excel? my data are in an excel. the dict exist only for reproducibility purposes

Comment: Why not? Just read the dataframe from your Excel file: `dict = pandas.read_excel("./myexcelfile.xlsx").to_dict(orient="rows")`

Comment: and then recreate the dataframe from the newly created dict?

Comment: Yep. Of course it's possible to do some of this stuff also within Excel (e.g. find all and replace)